# Convert 1 dataframe column into 2, splitting on slash, in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Let me share the data I am working with first, and then explain my struggle / what output I am hoping for:

```
head(my_df$HeightWeight)
"6-1 / 210"  "5-10 / 255" "5-10 / 165" "/" "6-0 / 200"  "5-11 / 185"

temp = c("6-1 / 210", "5-10 / 255", "5-10 / 165", "/", "6-0 / 200", "5-11 / 185")
```

The variable 'temp' is the dput() for what is displayed. This is height / weight information included in this column, and there are missing values (in my example the 4th is a missing value, represented as a /). I would like to split these into 2 columns, to get the following output:

```
head(new_df)
  Height     Weight
1    6-1        210
2   5-10        255
3   5-10        165
4     NA         NA
5    6-0        200 
6   5-11        185
```

it seems like this should be simple but I am struggling, any help appreciated!

Comment: `tidyr::separate` does this neatly, e.g. `my_df %>% separate(HeightWeight, c('Height', 'Weight'), sep = '/', convert = TRUE)`

Comment: `library(splitstackshape);cSplit(data.frame(temp = temp), "temp",  "/")`

Comment: amazing, thanks alistaire, that's a great function